# Permissions for API calls

Tags: apex, force.com, api, informatica

I need to do regular extractions from a Salesforce org where I'm not an Admin via Informatica. 
To do those calls, what privilages will I need? Do I don't think they want to make a sys admin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need "API Enabled" on your profile, plus "Read" access to any objects that you need to query. You will also need either "Read All" for the object, or they will need to make sure the sharing settings provide sufficient access for you to query the records you need access to.